# how can I show a byte array as image in my google action using Protobuf?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, actions-on-google

I´m developing an Action for Google, and I´m struggeling with the following situation:

According to Google Documents...

> Image source is a URL.

https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/rich-responses#df-json-basic-card

I´m working with C#. I have a Struct from type  where I packed each Attribute, one of them is Image, I should actually send a URL.. but when using the Controller for Pictures, I become a bytearray..

I´ve tried with this:

```
@"data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(response);
```

but It doesn´t work. Has anyone an idea on how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you create a separate endpoint to return an image file so that your card contains an actual URL?

Comment: Correct. The field needs to be a URL string of an image. E.g., `https://myhostname/myimage.png`

Comment: @NickFelker Thank you very much, I ended up doing that! :D